# Service Bus restarts the message processing once it has finished successfully in ReceiveAndDelete mode

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am receiving messages in `ReceiveAndDeleteMode` and the processing of messages restarts after the message has been successfully processed.

I have a TTL of 14 hours for the message and my code looks like this:

```
    private static async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
    {
       bool result;
       try
       {
         IQueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionString, serviceBusQueueName, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);

         var receivedMessageTrasactionId = Convert.ToInt64(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));

         result = await DataCleanse.PerformDataCleanse(receivedMessageTrasactionId);                                                           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          Log4NetErrorLogger(ex);
          throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Here is the Register Method that I have :

```
private static void RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()
        {
            IQueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionString, serviceBusQueueName);

            // Configure the MessageHandler Options in terms of exception handling, number of concurrent messages to deliver etc.
            var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
            {
                // Maximum number of Concurrent calls to the callback `ProcessMessagesAsync`, set to 1 for simplicity.
                // Set it according to how many messages the application wants to process in parallel.
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,

                // Indicates whether MessagePump should automatically complete the messages after returning from User Callback.
                // False below indicates the Complete will be handled by the User Callback as in `ProcessMessagesAsync` below.
                AutoComplete = true
            };

            // Register the function that will process messages
            queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessagesAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
        }
```

Please advise where am I doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have a `queueClient` in a method that gets a message as a parameter? Why is the `queueClient` never used? Do you call `Complete()` on the message after successful processing? So many questions... Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi @rickvdbosch Thanks for your response. I took this code from a git repository and was testing it. I have made some edits please let me know if its okay now.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing two `QueueClient` instances, and only one of them has the `ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete` flag. From the code you have provided, it looks like the one that has the flag is not being used. The client actually receiving messages is therefore in the default Peek/Lock mode. You should be able to remove the client from `ProcessMessagesAsync` and update `RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages` to use receive and delete.

```
private static void RegisterOnMessageHandlerAndReceiveMessages()
{
    IQueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionString, serviceBusQueueName);
    ///....
}
```

and then

```
private static async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
{
   bool result;
   try
   {
     var receivedMessageTrasactionId = Convert.ToInt64(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));

     result = await DataCleanse.PerformDataCleanse(receivedMessageTrasactionId);                                                           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Log4NetErrorLogger(ex);
      throw ex;
    }

}
```